# How is CollectionViewSource used in XAML?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding, collectionviewsource

Having the following XAML in my UserControl, I don't see anything in the ListBox:

```
<UserControl x:Class="SampleProject1.AutoCompleteTextBox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SmartSender.NET"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <x:Array Type="{x:Type sys:String}" x:Key="HTML5Tags">
        <sys:String>&lt;html&gt;</sys:String>
        <sys:String>&lt;body&gt;</sys:String>
        <sys:String>&lt;head&gt;</sys:String>
    </x:Array>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="X" Source="{StaticResource HTML5Tags}" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<Canvas>
    <Canvas.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Ellipse Width="7" Height="7" Fill="Blue" />
                <TextBlock Margin="6,0" FontFamily="Courier New" Height="16" 
                           Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Canvas.Resources>

    <TextBox Name="txt" Canvas.Left="0" Canvas.Top="0" KeyDown="txt_KeyDown"
             PreviewTextInput="txt_PreviewTextInput" />
    <ListBox Name="lst" Width="130" Height="120" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
             Visibility="Hidden" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" 
             ItemsSource="{StaticResource X.View}"
             KeyDown="lst_KeyDown" PreviewTextInput="lst_PreviewTextInput"/>
</Canvas>
```

I have tried with both `X` and `X.View` as `ItemsSource`. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First** of all `Visibility` is set to `Hidden` on your listBox. Remove that.

**Second** you need not to bind to `View` property if CollectionViewSource is defined in XAML. WPF internally convert CollectionViewSource to `ICollectionView` (`ListCollectionView` in your case) when binded directly from XAML.

This is how you bind in XAML (*Notice you have to set Source on binding and not directly*):

```
<ListBox Name="lst" Width="130" Height="120" Panel.ZIndex="1" 
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource X}}"
         KeyDown="lst_KeyDown" PreviewTextInput="lst_PreviewTextInput"/>
```

Comment: It was the second one. The first thing is actually a feature, not a bug. :)